# Mule 4 Publish consume component response jms body null after maximum wait time

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, mule-esb

Interaction scenario:
External resource (request) -> Mule ESB (publish jms to queue) -> ActiveMQ queue (rateRequest)
then wait for reply in response queue (rateResponse).

- Mule 4.1.1
- ActiveMQ 5.15.9
- mule-jms-connector 1.6.0

In integration project (mule) i used Publish consume component

```xml
<jms:config name="JMS_Config" doc:name="JMS Config" doc:id="0a098f4a-f2c3-4965-95dc-ac4bfec55511" sendCorrelationId="ALWAYS" >
    <jms:active-mq-connection >
        <jms:factory-configuration brokerUrl="${openBrokerUrl}" />
    </jms:active-mq-connection>
</jms:config>

<jms:publish-consume doc:name="Publish consume" doc:id="93227022-80b5-476c-9be7-1571064b3004" config-ref="JMS_Config" destination="rateRequest" sendCorrelationId="ALWAYS" requestReplyPattern="CORRELATION_ID">
    <reconnect count="10" />
    <jms:message outboundContentType="application/xml" outboundEncoding="UTF-8" >
        <jms:reply-to destination="rateResponse"/>
    </jms:message>
    <jms:publish-configuration persistentDelivery="true" />
    <jms:consume-configuration maximumWait="35" maximumWaitUnit="SECONDS" inboundContentType="application/xml" inboundEncoding="UTF-8"/>
</jms:publish-consume>
```

The problem is that after the end of 35 seconds sometimes JMS:TIMEOUT exception occurs (as expected), and sometimes returned a message with null body. Of course, there is no message with null body in response queue. Is this mule bug or I missed something?

Comment: What version of the JMS connector is used? The connector version is as important as the Mule version.

Comment: mule-jms-connector 1.6.0